# How to rewrite paths delivered by solr search (to view instead of node)

Tags: 7, views, uri, search

How can i rewrite the path of results delivered by solr search? Or is it possible to configure it the way i need?

The content of that particular website is organized in views. I do not want users to navigate to the node-view mode of the content, instead i want to redirect them to the specific views-page. Is there a way to show only views-pages as search-results? Or do i have to rewrite the links somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache Solr Views, or Search API Solr Search with Views, you can re-write the field in the usual Views way. Otherwise, you may need to fiddle with the search result template in your theme, which I realize is ugly.

A better choice would be to override the node display entirely, for example using Panels and creating a Page at node/% that overrides all node display for the appropriate content types. You can then customize the presentation of your nodes using Views that take the current node ID as an argument. This sort of thing is also possible using Display Suite, although that's a more complex solution. If you really always want people to see your node as presented by a View, you may as well solve this directly instead of by tweaking the search results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow the question completely, but if you are using facets along with Solr you could try out [Facet API Pretty Paths](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths).